# Unity: Video is working in editor but not on Android after build

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, video

I want to play a video in my game which is to be played on a Plane (GameObject). The problem is that video is working fine when playing in unity editor, but when I build and run it on android, it is showing only Plane but not video on it.
It is a simple low quality 5 seconds mp4 video (480x480 dimension), any hardware can easily support it.

I've tried enabling/disabling multi-threading.
I've also transcoded the video for Android with ->
Dimensions: Quarter Res (100x100)
Aspect Ratio: Stretch
Codec: Tried with all types (Auto, HP264, HP265, VP8)
Bitrate Mode: Low
Spatial Quality: Low Spatial Quality

I've also tried Render Mode with 'Material Overriede' and 'Camera Near Plane'. Both worked fine on editor but not on android.

I also tried waiting for 5 seconds while video was being prepared, and also tried playing video without Coroutine. Nothing worked.
I tried it on different Android devices but results were same.

Here's my Inspector of Plane (but I've tried with different settings too):

[image: Inspector of Plane]
<sub>(source: [promatican.com](http://promatican.com/Capture.PNG))</sub>

```
    public void VideoPlay(int num)
    {
        Application.runInBackground = true;

        StartCoroutine(VideoPlayCoroutine(num));
    }

    IEnumerator VideoPlayCoroutine(int num)
    {
        videoPlayer = GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
        videoPlayer.url = "Assets/videos/" + num + ".mp4";

        videoPlayer.Prepare();


        while (!videoPlayer.isPrepared)
        {
            //Debug.Log("Preparing Video");
            yield return null;
        }


        Debug.Log("Done Preparing Video");
        videoPlayer.Play();

        while (videoPlayer.isPlaying)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
        Debug.Log("Played Successfully!!");
    }



    public void VideoStop()
    {
        videoPlayer.Stop();
        StopCoroutine(VideoPlayCoroutine(0));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VideoPlayer.url is working on the file or HTTP URL.
And you should put the absolute URL on the build.

"Assets/videos/" + num + ".mp4" is relative path on the editor only.

If you want to use URL, you should put your videos to any server or local storage and pass it.

A simple solution is declare list of video clips and set to videoPlayer.clip.

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer))]
public class MyVideoPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private System.Collections.Generic.List<UnityEngine.Video.VideoClip> videoClips = null;

    private UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer videoPlayer = null;
    private IEnumerator playEnumerator = null;

    public void VideoPlay(int num)
    {
        Application.runInBackground = true;

        playEnumerator = VideoPlayCoroutine(num);
        StartCoroutine(playEnumerator);
    }

    public void VideoStop()
    {
        videoPlayer.Stop();
        if (playEnumerator != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(playEnumerator);
        }
    }

    private System.Collections.IEnumerator VideoPlayCoroutine(int num)
    {
        videoPlayer = GetComponent<UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer>();
        Debug.Assert(videoClips.Count > num);
        Debug.Assert(videoClips[num] != null);

        videoPlayer.clip = videoClips[num];

        videoPlayer.Prepare();

        while (!videoPlayer.isPrepared)
        {
            Debug.Log("Preparing Video");
            yield return null;
        }

        Debug.Log("Done Preparing Video");
        videoPlayer.Play();

        while (videoPlayer.isPlaying)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
        Debug.Log("Played Successfully!!");
    }
}
```