# Why doesn't my video play in the android smartphone but plays in the Unity Editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, video, rendering, video-player

I want to play a vertical video or a portrait video in Unity. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7iXEZGx2Mc&ab_channel=JimmyVegas) and was successfully able to implement .As per the video you create a raw image in the UI canvas. In the hierarcy you add an empty video player gameobject. Then in the project window you right click and create a render texture. You drag the render texture to the Target texture field in the Video player and the texture field in the raw image.

But the problem is create a I am able to play in my game view of Unity Editor but when I build on smartphone , it is not playing.

As per some suggestion I changed Codec of the video in the inspector from Auto to VP8 but there was no change at all.

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57351511/unity-video-is-working-in-editor-but-not-on-android-after-build), but I have not written any code as such. What I have done is as per that video.

Comment: And you want us to watch a video to work out what you may or may not have done. Please provide code and it in picture format

Comment: There is no code , but I will update the question explaining the procedure

Comment: @BugFinder I have updated the question. Would u mind to have a look?

Comment: It would need logs from the phone showing errors.

Comment: @BugFinder the only warning I am getting is WindowsVideoMedia error unhandled Color Standard: 0  falling back to default this may result in rendering issues